Route Docker container traffic through another container with iptables
This question is very similar to the one asked earlier, but there is a major difference, I would like to use iptables to solve the problem.
On the VPN server side, Strongswan is configured and successfully running in server mode (VPS). I have two Docker containers configured on my home server: a DCVPN container as a client to connect to the Strongswan VPN server and this connection works successfully and a DCWG container on which Wireguard is configured. On the user devices (WG Client 1 and WG Client 2) I can successfully connect to the DCWG VPN server.
Network schema
I ran into a problem when trying to configure forwarding of the connected Wireguard client traffic from the DCWG container to the DCVPN container. I'm not very network savvy, but I tried to configure all client traffic to be forwarded through iptables on DCWG:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.13.13.1/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 172.19.0.2 -j MASQUERADE

However, this did not work, because when I try to determine my external IP address, I get the IP address of my home server.
Docker command to run DCVPN:
docker run -d --name DCVPN \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
    --net=vpn \
    -e TIMEZONE=$TIMEZONE \
    -v /var/docker/vpn/data/strongswan.conf:/etc/strongswan.conf \
    -v /var/docker/vpn/data/ipsec.conf:/etc/ipsec.conf \
    -v /var/docker/vpn/data/ipsec.secrets:/etc/ipsec.secrets \
    -v /var/docker/vpn/data/ipsec.d:/etc/ipsec.d \
    vpn

Docker command to run DCWG:
docker run -d --name DCWG \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
    --net=vpn \
    -e TIMEZONE=$TIMEZONE \
    -e PUID=$PUID \
    -e PGID=$PGID \
    -e PEERS=$PEERS \
    -e SERVERPORT=$PORT \
    -e PEERDNS=8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1 \
    -p 51820:51820/udp \
    -v /var/docker/wireguard/config:/config \
    linuxserver/wireguard:latest

NAT rules on DCWG:
iptables -L -n -t nat --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       0    --  0.0.0.0/0            10.13.13.0/24        to:172.19.0.2

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER_OUTPUT  0    --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DOCKER_POSTROUTING  0    --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11
2    MASQUERADE  0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
3    MASQUERADE  0    --  0.0.0.0/0            172.19.0.2

Chain DOCKER_OUTPUT (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       6    --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11           tcp dpt:53 to:127.0.0.11:36145
2    DNAT       17   --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11           udp dpt:53 to:127.0.0.11:57760

Chain DOCKER_POSTROUTING (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    SNAT       6    --  127.0.0.11           0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:36145 to::53
2    SNAT       17   --  127.0.0.11           0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:57760 to::53

And as far as I can tell, traffic from WG Client 1 is not forwarded to DCVPN. I pinged google.com on WG Client 1 and got a response from the DCWG host:
tcpdump -i wg0 host 10.13.13.2
12:11:23.841895 IP 10.13.13.2 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 30840, seq 30840, length 64
12:11:23.896444 IP dns.google > 10.13.13.2: ICMP echo reply, id 30840, seq 30840, length 64
12:11:24.840582 IP 10.13.13.2 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 30840, seq 30840, length 64
12:11:24.895165 IP dns.google > 10.13.13.2: ICMP echo reply, id 30840, seq 30840, length 64
12:11:25.842555 IP 10.13.13.2 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 30840, seq 30840, length 64
12:11:25.897695 IP dns.google > 10.13.13.2: ICMP echo reply, id 30840, seq 30840, length 64

In other words, the problem sounds like I need to configure Wireguard over IKEv2 - to set up Connection 3. I would appreciate advice on what can be done to accomplish the goal.
